# Where is the classpath for hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I've been looking for the class path for the Hadoop mapreduce classes. I'm using Hortonworks version 2.2.4 sandbox. I need the classpath for running my javac compiler as such:

```
javac -cp (CLASS_PATH) -d /home/mypractice/ wordcount.java
```

Comment: You could try : `mapred classpath` or `hadoop classpath`.  For your case you could run : `javac -cp $(mapred classpath) -d /home/mypractice/ wordcount.java`

Comment: Why did someone rate my question down? its a fair question...

Comment: Not sure, it was not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the mapreduce classpath as such: $(mapred classpath). So the command is as follows:

```
javac -cp $(mapred classpath) -d *file*
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try print your classpath in the other jobs? then you will know the content of classpath.